# Disable design view on code-behind page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I often hit F7 when viewing the .aspx page I am working on to get to the code-beind, but sometimes just out of natural habit I hit F7 again (not sure why, but it happens often enough to be frsutrating).  Hitting F7 on the code-behind switches to design view for the .aspx which often times takes a while to render.

I already have 'source view' as the default open, but I would like F7 when in the code-behind to swap back to the .aspx source instead of design... is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/ToggleAspNetCodeBehind.aspx?print=true
with the following modifications should be what you need:

```
**Change the line:**
    OpenCodeBehindFile(activeDoc)
to:
  OpenCodeBehindFile(activeDoc & ".cs")

**Change the line in OpenCodeBehindFile from:**
  projItem.Open(Constants.vsViewKindCode)
to:
  projItem.Open(Constants.vsViewKindCode).Activate()
```

Reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/90ccfd68-c083-49a4-947a-03178d6af288/

Comment: This macro is perfect as-is. Install it, remove the keyboard shortcut for View.ToggleDesigner, and set the macro to F7. Then you can use F7 to swap between source and code.

Answer (score 7):

I have this behavior, and I thought it was this way out of the box, but I do have ReSharper installed. Looking at the keyboard settings my F7 is bound to "View.ViewCode (F7 (Settings Designer))" and "View.ToggleDesigner (F7 (Global))".